# If L = L1 U L2 is regular, L2 is the complement of L1 (which means L1 ∩ L2 = Ø), and we're given that L and L2 are regular, is L1 regular?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, closure-properties

L1, L2, and L are not finite. We're given that L and L2 are regular. However, L1 ∩ L2 is empty, since L2 is the complement of L1.

Is L1 regular under the property that regular languages are closed under union? I have been going back and forth about this for a while and any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $L_1$ is the complement of $L_2$ and $L_2$ is regular then $L_1$ must be regular since regular languages are [closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties) under complement. Furthermore, since $L_1$ and $L_2$ are complements and $L = L_1 \cup L_2$, then $L_1 = L - L_2$ and regular languages are also closed under relative complement.

But if you are asking if we can infer that $L_1$ is regular given only that $L_2$ and $L$ are regular without the condition that $L_1$ is complement of $L_2$, consider any non-regular language $L'$ and the regular language $\Sigma^*$. Notice that $\Sigma^* \cup L' = \Sigma^*$. So in general, the result of a union of a regular language and an arbitrary language can result to a regular language.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I know they're closed under complement, my question was specifically about using the property of closure under union if you have any thoughts on that!

Comment: @st00dent please see the my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

The language L1 is L \ L2. Take the FSMs for L and L2, create a new state machine whose states are pairs of states of these two FSMs, transitioning accordingly, and the accepting states are those that accept L but not L2.

Basically the same prove as for union or intersection or complement.